# can we display multiple records in displacy in spacy

Tags: spacy

I have been using space for quite some-time and I really liked the displacy

Is there a way where we can serve multiple texts from my data-set in the web-page as-in a small arrow to redirect to next record and mark the entities.
The code I'm using is as follows.

```
def validate(VAL_DATA):
nlp = spacy.load(args.model + '/nn')
for text, _ in VAL_DATA:
    doc = nlp(text)
    displacy.serve(doc, style='ent')
    for ent in doc.ents:
        print("entity: " + ent.label_ +"\t" + "text: " + ent.text)
```

VAL_DATA is my validation set and it has multiple records in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your question right, but if you want to mark entities found for mulitple docs you can just do the following:

```py
def validate(VAL_DATA):
    nlp = spacy.load(args.model + '/nn')
    docs = list(nlp.pipe(VAL_DATA))
    entities = [doc.ents for doc in docs]
    displacy.serve(docs, style="ent")
```

At least for me it worked just fine.
Might work fo you too?